# How to capitalize letters in custom keyboard in Jatpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, ime

I've been trying to figure out how to capitalize letters in my custom IME keyboard. I created capitalize key but I don't know what I have to put into

```
clickable(interactionSource = interactionSource, indication = null)
```

Maybe someone knows more how works with keyboard in Compose. Do you guys know how to achieve this in Jetpack Compose?

```
@Composable
fun KeyboardKeyCaps(
    keyboardKey: String, viewKeyboard: KeyboardViewModel
) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val pressed = interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val viewmodel = viewKeyboard
    val color by viewmodel.colorKeys.collectAsState()
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text(keyboardKey,
            Modifier
                .background(Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#" + color)))
                .border(3.dp, Color.Black)
                .clickable(interactionSource = interactionSource, indication = null) {
                    (context as IMEService).currentInputConnection.let {

                    }
                }
                .padding(
                    start = 12.dp, end = 12.dp, top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp
                )

        )
        if (pressed.value) {
            Text(
                keyboardKey,
                Modifier
                    .border(1.dp, Color.Black)
                    .background(Color.Gray)
                    .padding(
                        start = 13.dp, end = 13.dp, top = 17.dp, bottom = 17.dp
                    )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Usual Key

```
@Composable
fun KeyboardKey(
    keyboardKey: String, viewKeyboard: KeyboardViewModel
) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val pressed = interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val viewmodel = viewKeyboard
    val color by viewmodel.colorKeys.collectAsState()
    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Text(keyboardKey,
            Modifier
                .background(Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#" + color)))
                .border(3.dp, Color.Black)
                .clickable(interactionSource = interactionSource, indication = null) {
                    (context as IMEService).currentInputConnection.commitText(
                        keyboardKey, 0
                    )
                }
                .padding(
                    start = 12.dp, end = 12.dp, top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp
                )

        )
        if (pressed.value) {
            Text(
                keyboardKey,
                Modifier.graphicsLayer(clip = false)
                    .border(1.dp, Color.Black)
                    .background(Color.Gray)
                    .padding(
                        start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, top = 36.dp, bottom = 16.dp
                    )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots

[What I try to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epesl.png)

[What I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V1m0.png)

Comment: Are you creating a custom Keyboard app? Can you share a screenshot of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes I'm. I'm trying to create shift key for my keybord. I added screnshots in my question.

Comment: What do you do for non-capital letter?

Comment: add code of usual key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/IBRUTALI/KeyboardApp
There is the best example How to capitalize key in compose.